# Smoke Domain duplication over plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, duplicate

I am new to Blender but I've learned a lot since I started. I am used to CAD design so I understand how a blender works as long as it's explained to me. I am having a problem where I want to make a scene where the floor is on fire. I've succeeded in making the fire simulation but now I cannot find a way to spread the simulation to the rest of the plane. I tried making a smoke domain for the plane itself but the scales of the simulation were too big and made it so it covers the model. I cannot find a way to duplicate the domain either so I could just spread it along the plane. Is there any way to complete this scene? (For Example: Using some sort of duplication node to copy the small flame across the plane)

The photo below shows how far I've gotten. I have the fire simulated in a small patch and it looks great but now I want to use it to cover the whole plane.
[image: This is what I have so far... I have the plane and the fire but cannot spread the fire out while keeping the same flame height]

The fire is a basic Mantaflow Smoke Domain
(Domain Settings) [image]

Emitter Object Settings (Texture offset goes from 0.0 to .06 in 120 keyframes) [image]

This is what happens whenever I scale the Emitter Object and Smoke
Domain up and bake the data/noise [image]

I'd Appreciate any help on this matter!!
(Also I would add the .blend file but I cannot figure out how to link it)

Comment: @Chris I updated it, I'm not really sure what specific info you guys would need to help, but I'd appreciate it if you could re-read it and advise me on what else I should mention so that I can ask the correct questions! Also I couldn't figure out how to link the .blend file in the post.

Comment: just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.